# 4G LTE router network - ping works but no internet in browser on any connected device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CaaP.png)

Scenario: I'm surfing stackoverflow. Then something happen and I can't browse the site. But if I ping stackoverflow, it works.
Moreover this affects all connected devices to the router. There is not internet in browser on all devices, but can ping from all devices.

Atfer router restart all works fine for 10-50 minutes and again cant browse, but can ping.

**Update 09.01.2019**
It was working fine for a year

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by ping? Also if you don’t get any appropriate answer, you should switch to we applications SE

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade the firmware in this router?

Comment: Cmd - > ping stackoverflow.com

Comment: @John Its Huawei B311-220 and I checked through the web interface and firmware is up to date

Comment: How new / old is that router?  It does not come up on a Google Search

Comment: @John sorry, its huawei b311s-220, but very few result on Google, a I found document that says: initial official release 2017-12-12

Comment: That is relatively new. You say the firmware is up to date, so I cannot (quickly at this moment) see why it would drop connections

Comment: This thread (farther down) suggests the SIM card needed to be replaced. You might inquire about that. https://forum.three.ie/t5/Broadband-and-Data/B311s-220-Router-keeps-dropping-internet/td-p/37176

Comment: @John, SIM card has been replaced and nothing has  change. I will try other router.

Comment: Thanks. Please keep us posted

Comment: @John, I have tried Huawei Mobile 3s and it is all happening the same. But when I got out of flat with Huawei Mobile 3s,it works fine. So after that I have gone to other flat 1km further with Huawei B311-s220 and it was working too.
So there is something that affects Wifi or LTE. Huawei B311-s220 LTE signal indicator shows maximum. Is it possbile that maybe 
faulty electrical installation( exploding lightbulbs, ~1 week before the problems with internet) and its electromagnetic field affects Wifi or LTE signal? sounds abstract but...

Comment: @JamesP, forgot to mention, via Ethernet also not working. I have reseted few times to factory defaults. And to be sure if you have read my previous comment that in different localization it just works, both of the routers

Comment: And you are sure the devices work properly on a different connection entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[block of flats and BTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rbDA.png)

As you can see on the picture, cause of the problems was a weak signal(despite the router indicator was showing full strength) becouse in flat it was not working but when I went to corridor of block of flats with router, it was just starting to work. Even when I have placed the router after window it was not working and by that fact, I have drawn the possible BTS signal direction.

Moreover the connection was never dropped by router, but the download speed was dropping to extreme low value and with that speed browser was just killing the request after timeout. This is the reason why I was able to ping but not browse the websites. To be sure I made another test and I have developed a simple website with just one word on it. As I supposed, it was working, I was able to ping and browse this website when was in flat.

So the answer is: **too weak signal or too weak receivers in router.**